# $\ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)} $ without L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

> How do I find the following?$$\ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)} $$

I have tried to use trig identities :

$$ \frac{x}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)} = \frac{x}{\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x+\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\sin x} =  $$

Can't really see anything out of that?

***edit***- so based on Math lover hint :

$$\ \frac{x}{\cos \frac{\pi}{2}\cos x + \sin \frac{\pi}{2}\sin x} = \frac{x}{0 \cdot \cos x + 1\cdot \sin x } = \frac{x}{\sin x} = \frac{0}{0} = 0 $$

Comment: Now use $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ and $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$.

Comment: and the limit: $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @MathLover can you approve what I wrote is correct?

Comment: @bm1125 Just use the last step as $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{ \mathrm{sin}(x)}{x}}=1$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**

$$\cos(\frac \pi 2-x)=\sin(x)$$

Comment: Great, then we only need to go down the [following rabbit hole regarding sin(x)/x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative by $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ from the definition of derivative

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-0}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\frac1{f'(0)}=1$$

Comment: Thanks but still don't have the knowledge of derivatives.

Comment: @bm1125 You are welcome! Indeed I gace that as an alternative, the direct method by $sin x/x \to 1$ is of course better. For the proof refer to [sin x/x \to 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767)